# how to check a url is blocked by robots.txt

Tags: performance, indexing

I submitted my site in many sites , but it is not indexed by google , so how can i check if url is blocked. when i check those submitting websites robots txt file it shows that they blocked /sign-in url

indexing issue in link building sites